# How to find out all possible extractor types supported by Bizzflow.net?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I use Bizzflow.net ETL template installed in my GCP project. I would like to find out a list of extractor types, which could be configured within `type` value in `extractor.json`. Anybody knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` of the extractor is the name of particular repository name in [Bizzflow Eextractors](https://gitlab.com/bizzflow-extractors) GitLab group, for example MSSQL extractor has type `ex-mssql`. This is name of the same repo, where the extractor resists.